# blazorwasm template is missing in .NET Core 3.0 Preview

Tags: powershell, templates, blazor-client-side

I have just installed the last version of .NET Core 3.0 Preview

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-3.0.100-rc1-windows-x64-installer

To install the templates dotnet new has to be run from the Powershell command line. This works, but the blazorwasm template is missing. Updating the templates list with

dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.0.0-preview9.19457.4

does not deliver the blazorwasm template.

I have not installed the Visual Studio yet.

Answer (score 3):

try to install  preview 9.19465.2

dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.0.0-preview9.19465.2

work for me